# Pygame (Object Continual Movement)

Tags: python, object, pygame

Im in the process in making a snake game and my problem is understanding why using the code bellow keeps continually adding -10 or +10 to the lead_x value when the lead_x_change is incremented with an event to only increase lead_x by +10 or -10 1 event at a time? Thanks.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

#Colors
white= (255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
red= (255,0,0)

gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('ALIEN')

gameExit= False

lead_x=300
lead_y=300
lead_x_change=0

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit=True

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key== pygame.K_LEFT:
               lead_x_change =-1
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = 1

    lead_x += lead_x_change   

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,black,[lead_x,lead_y,10,10])
    pygame.display.update()





pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

#Colors
white= (255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
red= (255,0,0)

gameDisplay= pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('ALIEN')

gameExit= False

lead_x=300
lead_y=300
lead_x_change=0

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit=True

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key== pygame.K_LEFT:
               lead_x_change =-1
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = 1

        if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:

                if event.key== pygame.K_LEFT:
                    lead_x_change = 0

                if event.key== pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    lead_x_change = 0




    lead_x += lead_x_change   

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,black,[lead_x,lead_y,10,10])
    pygame.display.update()





pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Interesting this helped alot Thanks. I understand now that in the event of you lifting the key there's no change in the X value therefore it stops. You're the man!

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation about why the new code is necessary, and what it does. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.